# Designing a custom font for WebGL

Tags: fonts, text, 3d

Wondering if it's even useful to design a font using a tool such as [font-forge](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/index.html) if you are just going to use the font in a 3D environment such as with [Three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html#FF1F00111#three.js). It seems as though the font-file isn't necessary if you plan on doing that, and instead you just want to have a geometry file. But then there is the typing/entering text aspect, which I imagine you would have to implement on your own.

Wondering what the typical workflow is for a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-text),

> for procedural text geometry you need to create a mesh whose geometry is an instance of THREE.TextGeometry. In order for this to work, however, your TextGeometry will need an instance of THREE.Font to be set on its "font" parameter.

To use a custom font you need to export your custom font to the Three.js's JSON format, which can be done [using a python script for blender](http://www.jaanga.com/2012/03/blender-to-threejs-create-3d-text-with.html).

From that I suppose for dynamic texts the easiest route is to create a font file first. If you're just going to add 3D text that won't be generated on the fly then you probably don't need the font file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure - *I am engaging in educated **guessing** here* - but my guess is that the vector outline of the font (either its TT def or even a PS def) is being extruded live, given how responsive that demo is to typing new content... so I think the font file is in fact crucial.